# I am unable to access the internet

Tags: networking, drivers, internet

So... I recently installed Ubuntu on one of my old PCs out of curiosity, and it was working well.

My PC doesn't have an in-built wi-fi adapter so I use a USB one, and since wi-fi was slow anyways, I used an old router as an adapter and now I have a wired connection to the old router while the old router accesses the wi-fi of the main house router. Now get this: one day, I log in, and there is no wi-fi symbol, no wired connection, nothing.

I tried the solutions posted on this thread, as it matched my problem the closest: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2491006

Are there any tests I should run? Or data that I should post?

Comment: Too many variables. Do some clever testing and eliminate some possibilities. Start with the wired connection -- it's easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Is there any reason not to suspect something is wrong with "the old router"?